# Obtaining the index-value of a pointer class member list encapsulated by another class member which is a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, pointers, indexing

This one is a little strange to me.

I have a pointer to a class member (`mGeometry`), which, in turn, holds a pointer to a `QList< GLushort >` data member (`mFaces`). I am trying to get the index of mFaces via the class `Cube`.

So, the more simplified version would look like this:

```
struct Geometry
{   
    Geometry( void );
    ~Geometry( void );
    void someFunc( void );
    QList< GLushort > *mFaces;
};

class Cube
{   
 public:
    Cube( void );
    ~Cube( void );
    void anotherFunc( void );
    Geometry *mGeometry;
};
```

**Let's say, in `anotherFunc`, we're trying to do the following:**

```
GLushort *indeces = new GLushort;

*indeces = ( *mGeometry ).mFaces[ 0 ];
```

**Error(s)**

```
error: cannot convert ‘QList<short unsigned int>’ to ‘GLushort {aka short unsigned int}’ in assignment
```

**So, we try:**

```
*indeces = mGeometry->( *mFaces )[ 0 ]; //which, is originally how I've accessed pointers-to-containers' indexes.
```

**Error(s)**

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token

error: ‘mFaces’ was not declared in this scope
```

**And, of course, the obvious:**

```
*indeces =  mGeometry->mFaces[ 0 ];
```

**Error(s)**

```
error: cannot convert ‘QList<short unsigned int>’ to ‘GLushort {aka short unsigned int}’ in assignment
```

**Constructor for Geometry**

```
Geometry::Geometry( void )
    : mFaces( new QList< GLushort > )
{
}
```

Is there anything wrong I'm doing here? If not, what is the correct method to obtain the index of the pointer to `mFaces`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `mFaces` is a pointer, you have to dereference `mGeometry` with `->` then dereference `mFaces` with `*` then use `QList<>`'s `operator[]` to get the number:

```
*indeces = (*mGeometry->mFaces)[0]; // note that * has lower precedence than ->
                                    // so this is like (*(mGeometry->mFaces))[0]
```

It's a little weird because `[0]` does the same thing as `*`. Indices on pointer types, such as `x[i]`, follow the formula `*(x + i)`, so you can also do this for the same effect (but don't):

```
*indeces = mGeometry->mFaces[0][0]; // or *indeces = (*mGeometry).mFaces[0][0];
```

Which is the same as `(*(mFaces + 0))[0]`, which is exactly the same as `(*mFaces)[0]`.

That is also why you got that error `cannot convert ‘QList<short unsigned int>’ to ‘GLushort’` when you tried to do

```
( *mGeometry ).mFaces[ 0 ];
```

Because `( *mGeometry ).mFaces[ 0 ];` (which, again, is equivalent to the above `*mGeometry->mFaces`) gets you a `QList<GLushort>`, and you have to use the `operator[]` of `QList<>` to get your data.

And now for something completely unrelated, you misspelled *indices* :)

Comment: Ahh, thank you. Admittedly, I sprouted this from a file I found on the net (`render.cpp` - maybe you've heard of it?), and changed things around to make it more efficient. Again, I appreciate it. :)